# What are other LDAP and Active directory softwares

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, ldap

What is other best and realblie software like apache directory studio?

Comment: this should have been left on superuser, he's looking for an application to browse ldap or ad with.

Comment: But that would be quite useful to any admnistrators which has to deal with LDAP... which is not exactly a standard user issue, anyway.

Comment: you don't have to be an administrator to use these tools!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ADSIEDIT from Microsoft. You can either install it from the Windows Support Tools if you're running Windows XP/2003, or you can find it in the Remote Server Administration Tools from Windows Vista onwards.

Answer (score 4):

I tried [Luma](http://luma.sourceforge.net/) a bit but I find Apache Directory Studio to be the best tool.

On Wikipedia there is a [list of many LDAP clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_LDAP_software) that must contain the major ones.

Answer (score 3):

We use [ldapsh](http://ldapsh.com/) to browse thru the LDAP tree. It has tab-completion and you can edit each object as a file.:) Why ldapsh? because it give you more flexibility than clicking around the screen, copy, edit in realtime.

And yes it works with Active Directory. But we only use it with out LDAP.
Here's how it looks on AD.

```
ad-server.domain.com% ls
CN=Users                              CN=Infrastructure                     
CN=System                             OU=IIS Users                          
OU=Service Accounts                   CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals          
OU=Resources                          OU=ExtAuth                            
CN=Program Data                       OU=Domain Controllers
```

Comment: Unless you are a unix admin or a command line fan, I would recommend ADSIEDIT from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your needs, [phpLDAPAdmin](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) may be what you're looking for. Unlike Apache Directory Studio, it doesn't feature schema editing, but does support schema browsing.  However, if you just want a nice GUI LDAP client, phpLDAPAdmin is both lightweight and very reliable.  If you want a complete solution for LDAP development, then I agree with Nicolas Raoul, Apache Directory Studio is pretty hard to beat.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried several and IMHO apache directory studio is the best.

Answer (score 1):

I use Gowars LDAP Browse/Editor.  Java, 600K, lightweight, fast, cross platform.  The author seems to have disappeared, and taken his site with him, alas.

I found a link at [LBE description](https://www.opends.org/wiki/page/LDAPBrowserEditor) but the download link is broken.  But the screen shots are great.

Then I found this link, [LDAP Browser/Editor](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/8652/gawors-excellent-ldap-browsereditor-v282) that has the file to download.

This is missing some features, and the developer has disappeared, nonetheless, it is a powerful and basically works great!